# Is there any way to adjust the sequence of LegendEntries (Series) in Excel chart by VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, charts, series

I'm working on an Excel chart automation. When I try to move up a LegendEntry(Series) object, I cannot find any related API method from [MS site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193558(v=office.14).aspx). The manual way is like this: Select the chart > Right click > **Select Data...** > Choose one of the **LegendEntry** > Click button **Move Up**. How could I do this by VBA? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is another way

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim objChrt As ChartObject
    Dim chrt As Chart

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set objchart = ws.ChartObjects(1)
    Set chrt = objchart.Chart

    chrt.FullSeriesCollection(2).PlotOrder = 1
End Sub
```

**Screenshot**
[image]

Comment: I should metion that I'm using Excel 2010, so the object should be 'SeriesCollection' instead of 'FullSeriesCollection'. This is really helpful! Thank you for the clear demo.

Comment: Glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 2):

The legend entry order is the same as the series order. I'm not sure if this is even exposed in the object model. You can change the number of the last parameter of the series formula to re-order the series and the legend entries alike.

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
Debug.Print ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Formula
```

This will get you something like

```
=SERIES(Sheet1!$B$6,,Sheet1!$C$6,1)
```

The `1` as the last parameter means that it is the first series in the chart and hence the legend. Change that parameter to move the legend entry to a different position.

Comment: This is also helpful to look into the series. But I currently have some problem when I try to assign value to the series using this. So I switch to @siddharth 's way. Will try more when I got time. Thank you all the same!

Comment: Sid has it nailed with the PlotOrder property. That's what the last parameter of the series formula is.