# Run time error 91, activeChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries

Tags: excel, vba

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tbz3a.png)

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyXqM.png)
[Debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ABPJ.png)

This is the code I made when I try to use Macro Recording.
The problem is some errors happens when I run the Macro.
I know error happens might because VB Complier do not know which ActiveChart I am talking about.
But I do not know how to fix it. I will be super appreciate if someone can help me fix this problem.

Comment: `I know error happens might because VB Complier do not know which ActiveChart I am talking about` You need to declare your chart objects and work with them as shown [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44449982/is-there-any-way-to-adjust-the-sequence-of-legendentries-series-in-excel-chart). Also do not post code as image but copy and post the code in your question.

Comment: Another example of how to add and work with charts: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66363822/trouble-plotting-charts-through-vba/66364452#66364452